# Python keyboard event callback

Tags: python, linux, events, callback, key

I want some of my class functions to be called when a some keyboard keys are pressed, no matter which window is active. how to do that in LINUX. What I was using until now is OpenCV and waitKey() function but for that I need to show a window and have it active when pressing a keyboard key. I do have a main loop always running where the pressed key can be checked but it would be nice to have a solution where no loop is needed.

Comment: I think that you are looking for a *keylogger*

Comment: I am looking for a way to trigger functions at run time using the keyboard.

Comment: you want a program that registers a *global* keybinding. In `X` almost all keys are first intercepted by a window manager. If you want your program to see all key presses you need no do the same. I don't know how to do that exactly but you need to find a way to intercept all key presses. `Keyloggers` are the tools that do this.